# tensorflow Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) run model by data generator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I build a sequential model in Keras, when I use generator for the validation_data input, after 25 Epochs, the below error appears:

"Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"

```
 model.fit_generator(generator=trainGen, validation_data=validationGen , validation_steps=1, epochs=2000, steps_per_epoch=1)
```

Comment: I have to change TensorFlow 1.14

Comment: If that is the answer to your question, then post it as an answer and then accept it.